# Why does Visual Studio 2012 require me to provide construct/destroy for custom allocator?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, memory-management, c++11, stl, allocator

Since C++11 provides `std::allocator_traits` to simplify the use of custom `allocator`,
the minimum requirement of a custom `allocator` should be like this:

```
template <typename Tp> 
class SimpleAllocator 
{ 
    public: 
    typedef Tp value_type; 

    template <typename T> 
    struct rebind { typedef SimpleAllocator<T> other; };

    SimpleAllocator() {}

    template <typename T> SimpleAllocator(const SimpleAllocator<T>& other) {}

    Tp* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        // do the custom allocate here
    }
    void deallocate(Tp* p, std::size_t n)
    {
        // custom deallocate here
    }
};
```

(This is copied from [open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2946.pdf)) (I modified some format)

However when I compile this with a `std::vector<int, SimpleAllocator<int>>`, using VS2012,
the compiler wants me to provide the `construct` function,
so I am forced to implement  addional `void construct(Tp* p, const Tp& val)`
(and `void destroy(pointer p)`, of course).

Why is that? What am I missing? Or it's because VS2012 didnt provide full support?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a problem with the allocator_traits support from VS2012. Your example compiles fine with GCC. If you need deep information on what you need to make your own allocator you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator).

Comment: This behavior is known and seems to have been corrected in VS2013. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx?Redirected=true) for further explanations.

Comment: @Nemikolh REALLY THANK YOU!! That's very clear and strong information,  all I can say now is "good job, microsoft", lol!

Comment: You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of allocator is perfectly fine and compiles with GCC.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator), you'll find deep information about what is required for a minimal allocator and what can be re-implemented for a full allocator. It seems that VS2012's `std::allocator_traits` has a bug, and it supposed to be fixed in VS2013 as explained here:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx?Redirected=true